# pytorch cannot install using anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pytorch

`C:\Users\User>pip install pytorch`

When I run this command anaconda prompt display this error.

```
Collecting pytorch
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/67/f403d4ae6e9cd74b546ee88cccdb29b8415a9c1b3d80aebeb20c9ea91d96/pytorch-1.0.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
  Building wheel for pytorch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yto7o19p\\pytorch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-lqbohuk2' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yto7o19p\pytorch\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
      raise Exception(message)
  Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytorch
  Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
Installing collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py install for pytorch ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yto7o19p\\pytorch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oah_3fo2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yto7o19p\pytorch\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise Exception(message)
    Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yto7o19p\\pytorch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oah_3fo2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yto7o19p\pytorch\
```

`C:\Users\User>pip install torch`

When I tried to install `torch` it gives me this error message

```
Collecting torch
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/02/880b468bd382dc79896eaecbeb8ce95e9c4b99a24902874a2cef0b562cea/torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 544kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch) (5.1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: torch
  Building wheel for torch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-64iazehi' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
      description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all:
  ERROR: running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
Failed to build torch
Installing collected packages: torch
  Running setup.py install for torch ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-en00_2m3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-en00_2m3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5hkp2cz9\torch\
```

Other packsges can install by using `pip install` command but `pytorch` and `torch` didn't work like that

Comment: Looks like the solution is in the error message right here: `Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and install packages using the `conda` package manager when installing packages to your anaconda distribution (if possible)

Comment: Also take a look [here](https://pytorch.org/) to get the correct command to install `PyTorch`

Comment: I also tried to install torch. It gives me another error

Comment: Please use the instructions from the official website for installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conda install PyTorch -c PyTorch` is fine no need to run `pip3 install torchvision`

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for my problem. I have use this command

```
C:\Users\User>conda install PyTorch -c PyTorch
```

then I have run

```
C:\Users\User>pip3 install torchvision
```